# $2\csc^2(1-2x) = 2\cot(1-2x)\csc(1-2x)$ when using two different methods on same derivative.

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I was playing around with the following derivative:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{\sin(1-2x)}\right) $$

The way our teacher approached it was to transform the sine into a cosecant:
$$ \begin{align} 
\frac{d}{dx}( \csc(1-2x)) 
 &= -\csc^2(1-2x)\frac{d}{dx} (1-2x) \\\\
 &= 2\csc^2(1-2x) 
\end{align} $$

However, I also tried combining the chain and power rules:
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{\sin(1-2x)}\right) 
 &= \frac{-1}{\sin^2(1-2x)}\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(1-2x)) \\\\
 &= \frac{-1}{\sin^2(1-2x)}(\cos(1-2x))\frac{d}{dx}(1-2x) \\\\
 &= \frac{2\cos(1-2x)}{\sin^2(1-2x)} \\\\
 &= 2\cot(1-2x)\csc(1-2x) 
\end{align}$$

I also tried graphing them using desmos (blue, green and purple overlap):[image: graphs]

I want to know if both methods were correct, and if so, why are the graphs different and is there another way to demonstrate that these two terms are equivalent.

Comment: What is the derivative of $\csc(x)$? I think that's the only problem with your first computation. Otherwise the results will match.

Comment: I think you've mixed up the derivative of $\csc(x)$ with the derivative of $\cot(x)$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee you are absolutely right, thank you. I will bring this up to my teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\csc(1-2x)&=\left.\left(\frac{d}{dy}\csc(y)\right)\right|_{y=1-2x}\left(\frac{d}{dx}(1-2x)\right)\\\\
&=\left.\left(-\csc(y)\cot(y)\right)\right|_{y=1-2x}\left(-2\right)\\\\
&=2\csc(1-2x)\cot(1-2x)
\end{align}$$

which is precisley the same result as you obtained in the second approach.